# function setFaviconUrl() doesn't add favicon - why?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, favicon

this code is not working, and I don't know why. I have tried to change picture, tried .ico file and it didn't helped.
There is even no error in Chrome console.

It worked for some time, but it stopped woking "randomly" without any obvious reason.
Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setFaviconUrl(String))

```
   function doGet(request)
    {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Ahoj").setFaviconUrl('https://humandesign.cz/scripts/frontend/favicon.png').setTitle('FrontEnd');
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the format of your favicon? The [format](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO.

Comment: I tried using this feature as well and I've had similar problems.  I tried 32 x 32 png and gif and a 16 x 16 ico.  I also tried converting them to dataURI's and nothing seems to work. I just keep getting the standard image from Google.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be making it too the final page.  Here's the link from the elements panel `<link rel="shortcut_icon" type="image/png" ="">`

Comment: Can confirm my webapps are affected too, and had previously working PNG favicons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue and Google is working on a fix: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119627744