# GOOGLE BUSINESS - How to set a favicon to my site?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-search-console

There is an old tutorial from 2012:
"[Guide] How to change Favicon for Google Business Sitebuilder"
But it needs to be uploaded.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53550283/7215091) might be the problem.

Comment: I've seen it. I hope Google can fix that issue soon.